# Ray Hit than trigger keypress to enable object but can't figure out how to disable it later

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, gameobject

Working on a game with bullet holes, you look at the holes, and you get a prompt asking to trigger "e" the bullet trajectory (this all works fine) however I can't seem to make the bullet trajectory disappear (set false if it's active and distracting) if I want it too.

Any help would be great!

```
public class Trajectory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera    camera;
    public float     ray_Range = 5f;

    public KeyCode   interact;
    public GameObject interactUI;
    public GameObject GameObject;

    private bool activatedObject = false;

    void Start ( )
    {
        GameObject.SetActive ( false );
        interactUI.SetActive ( false );
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        Ray             ray_Cast = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
        RaycastHit      ray_Hit;

        if ( Physics.Raycast ( ray_Cast, out ray_Hit, ray_Range ) )
        {
            if ( ray_Hit.collider.tag == "Trigger" )
                interactUI.SetActive ( true );
            else
            {
                interactUI.SetActive ( false );
            }
            if ( ( ray_Hit.collider.tag == "Trigger" ) && !activatedObject )
            {
                if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( interact ) == false )
                {
                    GameObject.SetActive ( true );
                }
                else
                {
                    GameObject.SetActive ( false );
                }
            }
        }

        void SetFalse ( )
        {
            GameObject.SetActive ( false );
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of different configurations for setting false after and failed

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using a few `else` conditions that are contradicting your previous condition checks. In your case, you only want to check on a key down, and do nothing otherwise.

The resulting code would look like:

```cs
public class Trajectory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
    [SerializeField] private float _rayRange = 5f;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _interact;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _interactUI;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _gameObject;

    void Start ( )
    {
        _gameObject.SetActive ( false );
        _interactUI.SetActive ( false );
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        // If screen size/orientation can't change, we could cache this midpoint vector as a micro-optimisation.
        var rayCast = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));

        if ( Physics.Raycast ( rayCast, out var rayHit, _rayRange ) )
        {
            if ( rayHit.collider.CompareTag ( "Trigger" ) )
            {
                if ( !_interactUI.activeSelf ) 
                    _interactUI.SetActive ( true );

                // ONLY switch active state if the key was pressed this frame.
                if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( _interact ) )
                    _gameObject.SetActive ( !_gameObject.activeSelf );
            }
            else
            {
                if ( _interactUI.activeSelf ) 
                    _interactUI.SetActive ( false );
                if ( _gameObject.activeSelf ) 
                    _gameObject.SetActive ( false );
            }
        }
    }
}
```